# Program to draw a list with some dotted lines indicated the hierarchical structure

Tags: windows

I am looking for a Windows program with which I could draw a hierarchical list with some dotted lines that indicates the hierarchical structure, as some file browsers show:

[image]

(I don't want any icon, just text + dotted lines any other visual indicator showing the hierarchical structure)

I don't want to use any graphics editor: it should be as easy / convenient as making a bullet list in a text editor (Microsoft Word/LibreOffice/etc).

Comment: Exactly what do you want to apply this to? A plain text file? File directory? Some other stuff?  Is the indent guide in Notepad++ sufficient for you? See if-statement in the middle of this picture: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/assets/images/scsh/scsh_gui_minimalist.png

Comment: @holroy I want to apply this to any kind of hierarchical list of strings. Eventually I want to export it as PDF (or at worst take a screenshot of it), to insert it as a figure in some Word or LaTeX document. I am basically trying to make the hierarchical list as visually appealing as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that immediately made me think of the Linux `tree` command and got me to wondering if there is a Windows port of it.

While googling, I stumbled across http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/07/5-command-prompt-hacks-you-probably-dont-know/

Take a look at number 3: Dos itself has a `tree` command and the output looks like this:

[image]

Is that what you wanted, or did I somehow miss the point?

Comment: thanks, I'm looking for something that restricted to file/folder but any kind of bullet list

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest [ascii-tree](//www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-tree) — *A node module for generating a text tree in ASCII*.

An input and output example using this npm module:

```
Input:
  #root node
  ##node1
  ###node11
  ##node2

Output:
  root node
  ├─ node1
  │  └─ node11
  └─ node2
```

If you take your text line input, and do a simple replace in the start to replace leading spaces with a correct number of <kbd>#</kbd> characters, this script should provide the wanted output.

The module is based upon [freetree](//github.com/liushuping/freetree) and can possibly be extended/modified/configured into handling text using leading space as indentation directly. If the drawing characters are not already in unicode, you might want to look into that as well.

Comment: Another variant over this theme could be found at http://www.acooke.org/cute/PythonCode0.html

Comment: Nice, thanks! I'm not especially looking for ASCII-only but that can be definitely very useful for some situations.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt,  I don't think it is restricted to ascii, the included example is using unicode characters, and I guess python is unicode safe as well.

Comment: The other variant is also some general code which could be used if you are up for a little programming... :-)